# Passport "Error: Failed to serialize user into session" for multiple models

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I have two models that can login(none of them is user) one is applicant and other one is employer.
the passportEmployer config file is this which is similar to the passportApplicant config file.

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var Employer = require('../controllers/EmployerController');

//passport middleware
passport.serializeUser(function(employer, done) {
    done(null, employer._id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Employer.findById(id, function (err, employer) {
        done(err, employer);
    });
});

//passport local strategy
passport.use( 'employer', new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    session: false
  },
    function(username, password, done){

        Employer.find({email:username}, function(err, employers){
            if(err) {
                return done(err, null, null);
            }

            var employer = employers[0];
            if(!employer){
                return done(null, false, { 'confirmation':'fail', message: 'Unknown Employer'});
            }

            Employer.comparePassword(password, employer.password, function(err, isMatch){
                if(err) {
                    return done(err, null, null);
                }
                else if(isMatch){
                    return done(null, Employer, {'confirmation':'success', 'result':employer});
                }else{
                    return done(null, false, {'confirmation':'fail', message: 'Invalid Password'});
                }
            });
        });
    }
));

module.exports = passport;
```

and the following login route:

```
router.post('/employer/login', function(req, res, next){
    employerPassport.authenticate('employer', function(err, employer, info){
        if(err) {
            res.status(400).json({'confirmation':'fail', 'message':err})        
        }
        else if(!employer){
            res.status(400).json(info)
        }
        else{
            req.login(employer, function(err){  
                if(err){
                    res.status(400).json({'confirmation':'fail', 'message':'error'+err})
                }else{
                    console.log('Authentication Successful');
                    res.json(info)  
                }
            });
        }
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

but this gives the following error:
"message": "errorError: Failed to serialize user into session"

please help.

Answer (score 1):

compare your local strategy with the following one.There is a typo in your code.Also, query for a single employer using `Employer.findOne()` instead of `Employer.find()`

```
//passport local strategy

  passport.use( 'employer', new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email',
   passwordField: 'password',
   session: false
  },
   function(username, password, done){

    Employer.findOne({email:username}, function(err, employer){
        if(err) {
            return done(err, null, null);
        }
        if(!employer){
            return done(null, false, { 'confirmation':'fail', message: 'Unknown Employer'});
        }

        Employer.comparePassword(password, employer.password, function(err, isMatch){
            if(err) {
                return done(err, null, null);
            }
            else if(isMatch){
                return done(null, employer, {'confirmation':'success', 'result':employer});
            }else{
                return done(null, false, {'confirmation':'fail', message: 'Invalid Password'});
            }
        });
    });
}
));
```